# Bootstrap 4 in Angular, installed using npm adding a custom.css file

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have installed bootstrap 4 in an Angular app using npm.

I need to add a custom.css file so I can customize bootstrap variables values etc.

How do I do this?

Do I create a custom.css file and place it in the application assets folder or how does this work?

Comment: Yes. One thing you DO NOT do is add or modify the files under the `node_modules` folder. Assets is the intended place for your files. Do you know how to use that custom.css file in your project once it's there?

Comment: No, I do not know how to use the custom file ones it's there ... Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Start by telling us what library you used. Doesn't it have documentation?

Comment: `angular.json > "architect" > "build" > "styles"` add `"src/assets/custom.css"` You could also just add your custom styles to `src/styles.css` ... that depends on how modular you want to be with your styles.

Comment: So, would the variables work in my styles.scss file if I used scss?

Comment: I'm not sure what "variables" you are referring to, but yes, variables are supported in the styles.scss file

Comment: Thanks all for the advice